# Strategy For Interacting Instances Of The Same Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Imagine you have a model like the one below. On each musician's page you want to show other musicians that have the same agent.

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent)
```

Additionally, you want to a run a method to be shown on the musician's page. The method works out the similarity between the current instance and all the related instances that share the same agent.

```
def similarity(self, other_instance)
    ...
    return similarity
```

Therefore, the template needs the following:

1. Details of current musician
2. Details of related musicians and their similarity to the current musician

Is there are Django-approved way to approach this problem? Would it make sense to use class-based views for a problem like this?

Comment: What do you have so far ? This looks pretty straight forward

Comment: My main question is where and how to call the "similarity" function. For example, should it be a method that is called on the particular instance? In that case I would need to run a queryset within a model instance. I wasn't sure if that's an acceptable practice. Alternatively I could call the "similarity" function in the view? My main question is getting a sense of how the similarity function should be used, especially given that it needs to know about related instances.

Answer (score 0):

To "show other musicians that have the same agent.", use this query `musician.agent.musician_set`

```
def detail(request, musician_id):
    musician = get_object_or_404(Musician, pk=musician_id)
    return render_to_response('musician/detail.html', {'musician': musician})
```

And in your template:

```
<h1>{{ musician.first_name }} {{ musician.last_name }}</h1>
```

And for related:

```
{% for related_musician in musician.agent.musician_set %}
   #show related musician details
   {{ related_musician.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already understand how to achieve that. My question is more related to running the "similarity" method detailed above and how that information should flow through the system.

Comment: @user3246023 If I understand your question correctly, I don't think django or class-based views have anything to do with your problem. You are trying to implement some algorithm to find similarities between two  different instances. and this is something django will not tell you how to do it

Comment: I have already written the algorithm to compare the similarity of two instances. My question relates to where and how the function should be used. For example, should it be a method attached to the current instance, and therefore everything would be handled in the model itself? In that case, I would surely need to run a queryset from within a model instance. Or should the function be called in the view?